# Как отменить команду git add *

Tags: git, git-add

Следующей командой были добавлены все файлы с основной папки:

`git add *`

Вопрос: как очистить все добавленные файлы? Коммит еще не был сделан. Просто удалить проиндексированные файлы?

Comment: `git rm --cached <имя файла>` (С) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348170/how-to-undo-git-add-before-commit

Comment: @Lexx918 Вы ссылку дали на один ответ а написали другой в комментарии. Не вводите в заблуждение. Топикстартеру явно нужно убрать файл из индекса а не из репозитория

Comment: @tutankhamun я дал ссылку на аналогичный вопрос, а не на ответ. среди ответов там есть и тот что я процитировал.

Comment: @Ross, ваш вопрос содержит неоднозначную формулировку. ". Просто удалить проиндексированные файлы" - удалить именно файлы или удалить из индекса?

Answer (score -1):

Обратной к `add` является команда `git rm`

**UPD**

Помятуя о том, что [не все советы одинаково полезны](https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/05/90.html), сначала стоит заглянуть в `man`

> git-rm
>
> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index.
>   …
>   When --cached is given … allowing the file to be removed from just the index.
>
> --cached 
>   Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Перевожу на русский: `git rm --cached` удаляет файлы только из индекса.

Comment: то есть что бы отменить все - git rm -all ?

Comment: Это не так. git rm удаляет файлы. В вопросе требуется убрать файл из индекса. Причем git rm --cached позволяет закоммитить удаление только из репозитория не удаляя файл из рабочей директории